# Can't deserialize JSON to list in C#. No integer (0-n) indexes

Tags: c#, json

How can I deserialize JSON to a list using DeserializeObject and JsonProperty while the indexes of the elements are non-integer?

JSON:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "TEST": {
    "360450323_188530139": {
      "id": "24216",
      "name": "zxc",
      "desc": "cxz"
    },
    "310777518_0": {
      "id": "6458678634",
      "name": "dfgsfd",
      "desc": "sdfxcvnbhr"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to make a list from that?

I've tried:

```
using(WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    var url = "...";
    var json = wc.DownloadString(url);
    Result result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(json);
}

public class Result
{
    [JsonProperty("success")]
    public string Success { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("TEST")]
    public List<Test> Tests{ get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int id { get; set;}

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("desc")]
    public string Desc { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the JSON items would have to be in an array (i.e. wrapped in [] instead of {}) to deserialize to a list.

Comment: Looks like the JSON is invalid, missing a `,` in between your test items.

Comment: It seems like you might want to deserialize it to a Dictionary<string,Test> and pull the Values collection out of that....

Comment: In addition to previous comments, if you want to deserialize the id to an int, it should not be under quotes in the JSON. When a value is under  " " in the JSON, it is treated as a String, not a numeric value

Comment: @OmriAharon, there is a comma. Just failed while editting the JSON. Was too big.

Comment: @AleksandarStojadinovic, I didn't mean the "id" as an index. I want to deserialize those two elements: "360450323_188530139" and "310777518_0"

Comment: I didn't quite understand. I'm just saying your JSON is not aligned with your model, as far as I see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a keyed collection in the JSON, which maps easily to a dictionary. You could examine result.Test.Values

```
using(WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    var url = "...";
    var json = wc.DownloadString(url);
    Result result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(json);
    // result.Values should contain the Test instances at this point.
}

public class Result
{
    [JsonProperty("success")]
    public string Success { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("TEST")]
    public Dictionary<string,Test> Tests{ get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
// omitted - same as in question.
}
```

Comment: Works with the Dictionary. Thank You.

Comment: Also, the keys in the dictionary will be those IDs that it wasn't clear you were trying to extract... Also useful.